# How to restore my system to good condition on linux mint 20?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, restore

I booted from Linux Mint Live from USB with the aim to separate /home from / separate partition

I mounted both the partitions and by mistake moved wrong files to wrong place (while using sudo)

```
mount /dev/hda9 /mnt/liunx-home
mount /dev/hda7 /mnt/liunx-root
```

I moved /mnt/liunx-root/* to /mnt/liunx-root/var by mistake

```
mv /mnt/liunx-root/* /mnt/liunx-root/var by mistake
```

How can I recover my system back to normal without having to reinstall?

Comment: Edit the question to show, don't describe: What commands did you do?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Move it all back, except for what should be in `/var`.

Here is what I have in `/var`, hope it helps. (I am on Debian 10.)

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4.0K Oct 21 07:56 backups/
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root  4.0K Aug 12 17:37 cache/
drwxr-xr-x 60 root root  4.0K Aug 12 17:37 lib/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4.0K May 13  2019 local/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Aug  5  2019 lock -> /run/lock/
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4.0K Oct 21 07:56 log/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail  4.0K Sep 23 12:29 mail/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4.0K Aug  5  2019 opt/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 Aug  5  2019 run -> /run/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4.0K Oct  9 19:41 snap/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4.0K Nov  2  2019 spool/
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root  4.0K Oct 21 07:51 tmp/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I reinstalled the Linux as I needed it urgently and cold not wait.